# Embedding a video on https website becames not a secure connection

Tags: html, video, https, embedding

I have a problem including a video inside a website which runs in https mode. Chrom and Safari works fine and the connection is secure, but Firefox has the meaning that the connection is not secure. Sometimes Firefox says the connection is secure. Thats a random effekt.

I have created a test page:

https://www.aquarienpflanzen-shop.de/test.html

My embedding code

```
<video controls height="202" width="360" style="float:left; margin:10px" title="Die echte Riesenvallisnerie im Video">
<source src="/video/vallisneria americana und australis.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="/video/vallisneria americana und australis.webm"  type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Chrom and Safari say it is secure and Firefox is always changing.

Does anybody has an idea what I need to change? Could it be a Firefox bug or is my video embedding the problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this page in Firefox Private window, I think it's a cache problem.

I've tried it on my firefox Developers Edition and it's Secure.

Also try to clear the cache.